# How do I play an audio file on page load?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website. I have a specific page. I need to play WMV file on page load. I have uploaded the wmv file. When i run it, it gives nothing.

Here is the code

```
Imports System.Media
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim loca As String
    loca = Server.MapPath("../audioo.wav")
    Dim a As New SoundPlayer(loca)
    a.PlayLooping()
End Sub
End Class
```

the file is WAV and all other examples on net use mp3

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server side code and client side code. The VB.NET code executes on the server. Assuming there is a console associated with the process, then you would hear the music *on the server*. That's probably not what you want. When ASP.NET executes, it sends the resulting HTML, CSS, and JS to the client. You need to look for a client side solution involving those 3 technologies. Additionally, you said it's a WMV file but your code shows a WAV file. Which is it?

Comment: yes i understand. may be you are right. i need Javascript.

Comment: can you help me and write for me javascript and xhtml code. all i need is to play the file automatically on page load

Comment: There's lots of examples of that on the Internet. Try one of them. If you get stuck, then show your attempt here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest method for playing MP3 on web page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155376/simplest-method-for-playing-mp3-on-web-page-load)  Also I think on Windows OS can play **wav** files.

Comment: i try using audio tag. it gives nothing

Comment: and when using embed tag, autoplay and loop attributes are not supported. and when i run the file, mozilla tells that file is not supported

Comment: @Tarek *Show your work*. We can't help you if you just describe your code. You need to put your code in your question. Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tarek Follow this link [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-1/) and try to implement it. When struck somewhere we are here to help you.

Comment: @Suprabhat Thank you. i will try it

Comment: Thank you all. it works. Thanks for God.

Comment: i converted the wav file to swf and use embed tag and it works